# GLSL - setting uniform issue

Tags: java, glsl, libgdx

I went into a little problem here, My render loop doesn't render my world because of GLSL issues.

The program updates the uniform in the render loop :

```
map[mapPos].light = Lighting.checkSunLight(mapPosY, mapPosX, this); // It works good.. returns float
Shaders.blockS.begin();
Shaders.blockS.setUniformf("lightBlock", map[mapPos].light); // Problem is here!!!
Shaders.blockS.end();
batch.draw(map[mapPos].getBlockTexture(), (mapPosX * Block.WIDTH), (mapPosY * Block.HEIGHT),     Block.WIDTH, Block.HEIGHT); // Doesn't draw the block.
```

Just if you curious about the fragment shader -

```
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform vec2 screenSize;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 gameTime;
uniform float lightBlock;

const float RADIUS = 0.75;

const float SOFTNESS = 0.6;

void main() {

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);

    vec4 timedColor = (vColor + gameTime);

    vec2 position = (gl_FragCoord.xy / screenSize.xy) - vec2(0.5);
    float len = length(position);

    float vignette = smoothstep(RADIUS, RADIUS-SOFTNESS, len);

    texColor.rgb = mix(texColor.rgb, texColor.rgb * vignette, 0.5);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texColor.rgb * timedColor.rgb * lightBlock, texColor.a);
}
```

Pedantic is

```
ShaderProgram.pedantic= false;
```

Comment: Could you check whether an OpenGL error occurs on that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, I just moved the `.end()` function of the shader program to the last line.

Comment: I take it `begin (...)` does something like `glUseProgram (glsl_prog)` and `end (...)` does `glUseProgam (GL_NONE)`? Your answer as it stands right now is not particularly helpful if anyone comes across a similar issue in the future. You did not provide enough context to explain why this fixed your problem.